# How to continue the underline if the text is divided into two part

Tags: html, css, underline

**Edited**

My question is completely different from the duplicate question. I am talking about the underline should continue till the end of the text. No matter whether it's divided into one, two or three line

I have to show the underline below the anchor tag and I have tried the code below but am getting one issue. I have set the width 300px to the ul tag and anchor text divided into two parts but the underline not showing the divided text.

**Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

I have to show underline below the "of mentoring" also

```css
ul {
  width: 300px
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #000;
}

ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="">The role of mentoring</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="">Research backed benefits of mentoring</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: @savageGoat, do you mean it's not possible with CSS?

Comment: `text-decoration` solution wins, hands down

Comment: @savageGoat, text-decoration will solve the problem but I don't want to use it.. i have customized the underline and I belive we can't customize the text-decoration

Comment: it's limited but `text-decoration-color` sets the color and `text-decoration-thicknes` the height, but it's still plain CSS which is a better solution if the point is to make it simple. Otherwise you could use may solution for more advanced customizations

Comment: did you open the duplicate? or simply read the title?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using `text-decoration` and `text-underline-offset` :

```css
ul {
  width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul a {
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-thickness: 10px;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  text-underline-offset: -7px;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="">The role of mentoring</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Research backed benefits<br> of mentoring</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: appreciate your answer but i have to use :after css

Comment: Ok, glad to help, maybe you can explain the reason for using `:after`?

Answer (score -1):

Since your underline is `absolute`, this should do the trick.
Note that this is not the optimal solution since it strips the HTML tags inside the `a` element.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".underline").forEach((block) => {
  block.innerHTML = block
    .innerText
    .split(' ')
    .map((word) => `<span class="underline-wrap">${word}</span>`)
    .join(' ');
});
```

```css
    ul {
      width: 300px
    }

    ul,
    li {
      list-style: none;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul li a {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 28px;
      line-height: 32px;
      color: #000;
    }
    ul li a.underline {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden; /* hide excess of line produces by left: -10px; right: -10px;*/
    }
    ul li .underline-wrap { position: relative; }
    ul li .underline-wrap:after {
      content: "";
      background-color: red;
      height: 10px;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 5px;
      left: -10px; /* fill gaps between words */
      right: -10px; /* fill gaps between words */
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="underline">The role of mentoring</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="" class="underline">Research backed benefits of mentoring</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Mods being mods, since it's a duplicate there should only be one answer. You'll get used to it

Comment: No, there is no duplicate question. i have explained in the question